# JAVA basic iterator

Tags: java, iterator

this was the solution to my homework and the purpose was to reverse each word in a string based on user inputting a sentence. I have completed this on my own, but I'm just wondering how the iterator worked in this piece of code. I don't understand the delcaration of tempword = ""; and how he printed out each word delimited by spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReverser
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String sentence;
        String word;
        String tempWord = "";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner wordScan;

        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        sentence = scan.nextLine();

        wordScan = new Scanner(sentence);

        while(wordScan.hasNext())
        {
            word = wordScan.next();

            for(int numLetters = word.length() - 1; numLetters >= 0; numLetters--)
                tempWord += word.charAt(numLetters);

            System.out.print(tempWord + " ");
            tempWord = "";
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please realize that it's Java and not JAVA

Comment: though it is off topic, this piece of code is really a bad example of using String for consecutive concat.  Use StringBuilder/StringBuffer for that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this bit adds in the spaces

```
System.out.print(tempWord + " ");
```

this bit reverses it

```
for(int numLetters = word.length() - 1; numLetters >= 0; numLetters--)
            tempWord += word.charAt(numLetters);
```

this bit sets it up for the next word

```
tempWord = "";
```

Comment: i understand the for loop completely, but how is tempWord = ""; setting it up for the next word? Sorry i'm a complete dumbass

Comment: its emptying it. its saying im finished with that word, and im going to reuse the string to start holding each char in the next word

Comment: how does it know when to reverse it at each space then print that segment?

Comment: A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

Comment: the hasNext() bit is where it has chopped the sentence up in to words

Comment: Yes I understand that, so the word. = wordScan.next() will only read the broken up parts?

Comment: Ok thank you so much, almost completely understand this code. But still do not understand how tempWord = ""; at the end is resetting it?

Comment: It needs to make it an empty string for when it is processing the next word

Comment: OH so that the same text is not printed out again... I see now Thank you so much, is there like a rep system here

Comment: WAIT one more! sorry! String tempWord = ""; why is this declared at the beginning? is it necessary??

Comment: You could declare it each time, but it's quite an overhead. So its best to declare it once and re-use it.

Comment: Ok thank you, I do not know anyone else in the world could have explained it step by step like you did. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop counts backwards, from the index of the last character in the word to the first (in zero based notation)

The print prints the reversed word + a space (" "), the fact it uses print in place of println is because println would add a carriage return putting each word in a different line.

The tempWord = ""; at the end of each iteration reset the variable so it can be reused.

Comment: Thanks I understand the for loop completely but wouldn't the line  tempWord += word.charAt(numLetters);

        System.out.print(tempWord + " "); print the whole setennce?

Comment: at every iteration a new character is added to tempword. at the end of a cycle of iterations ie once a word is done, tempword is printed, emptied and the cycle restarts with the next word

Comment: a good but tedious way to learn is to "simulate" it yourself following the algorithm line by line on a piece of paper,keeping track of all the variables

Comment: I spent 2 hours looking at this trying to figure it out before posting here, and finally I couldn't get the large concept but now I do. Thanks anyway